# Running a c++ and a python script simultaneously causing problems

Tags: python, c++, linux, raspberry-pi

at the moment I've got the problem, that I'm forced to split my project into a python and a c++ script as they have hardware specified libraries I need. As part of my project the c++ script creates the rgb data for my led strips and the python script uploads them to the led's. Therefore I need an information exchange between the programs as the led's have to be refreshed all the time and this leads us to the main issue. The c++ script writes data into an .txt file and writes a trigger2.txt file. The python script is constantly waiting for the trigger file and don't starts until it shows up. After the Python script is done it also creates a trigger.txt file so the c++ script knows it can start again.
When I run my program it uploads the rgb data one time but stops then. It seems like that after the c++ script starts the python script and it has uploaded the rgb data, the c++ can't continue as the the python script is asking for the trigger2.txt in the while loop. Like the c++ script is waiting as the second on the process list for the finishing of the python script.

Here is the c++ script:

```
int main(){
int counter = 0;
int a;

while(1){

a=0;
  if (counter>0){                   //If counter==0 it's the first time an no trigger is needed
    while(a<1){
        std::ifstream FileTest("trigger.txt");  //If the trigger file exists the script can start again
        if(FileTest){
            a++;
            system("sudo rm trigger.txt");      //cleaning the folder
            }
        else
            std::cout << "Can't find trigger.txt" << std::endl;
    }
  }
if (a==1||counter==0){

/////The rgb data is generated here

    std::fstream file;              //Writing the .txt to transfer the rgb data
    file.open("rgb.txt", std::ios::out);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3;i++)
            file << rgbmatrix[i]<< std::endl;
    file.close();
    system("sudo touch trigger2.txt");      //The Python script can start now to refresh the led's

    if (counter==0){                //The first time led.py will be started manually
    system("sudo python led.py");
    zaehler++;
    }
}
}
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the python script:

```
rgb = [1,2,3]
i=0
import time
import sys
import os

while 1:
  if (os.path.exists('/home/pi/rgbwired_v2/trigger2.txt')):
    os.system("sudo rm trigger2.txt")
    file = open("rgb.txt","r")
    rgb = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    rgb = [int(i) for i in rgb]

    #RGB data will be uploaded here

    sys.stdout.write('led printed')
    os.system("sudo rm rgb.txt")
    os.system("sudo touch trigger.txt")

  else:
    sys.stdout.write('File not found')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I appreciate all of your help. Thanks.
(I'm working with the Raspberry Pi)

Comment: would it be a problem to call the c++ program from within the python script? because if not you could try that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it didn't fixed the problem but now I'm pretty sure that my suspicion was right. Now after I changed my code it only runs the while loop of my c++ script  on and on. It really seems like that the scripts can't alternate. What can I do against that :/?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the C++ program do the work it has to do you could call it from your python script, read its output and send some input when you need to do some more work. In order to achieve this you could use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library provided by python.

Your C++ code would then need wait for some special input (e.g. a new-line-character '\n' or something like that), then calculate what needs to be calcualted and then write the data to `stdout` and then write a line that indicates the end of the dataset (e.g simply write 'end', or a blank line)

Your python code would look something like this:

```
import subprocess

#Start the c++ program
process = subprocess.Popen(['<path to the c++ executable>', <arg1>, <arg2], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
#Grab its output
p_out = process.stdout
#Grab its input
P_in = p.stdin

while True:
    p_in.write('\n')
    lines = []
    line = p_out.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()
    while line:
      <process the read data>
      line = p_out.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: I'm not not familiar with this subprocess, but when you're saying it waits for the termination of the c++ program, you mean its completely finished? As the initialisation of the c++ program is taking too much time, I'm not able to start it again and again. The full termination isn't possible, that's why I'm using the while loop.

Comment: I edited my answer so you only need to start the c++ programm once.